# Mean of values ${1 \over m} {\sum_{i=1}^m {s_i \over t_i}}$ vs. Value of sums ${\sum_{i=1}^m {s_i} \over \sum_{i=1}^m {t_i}}$, What is the relation?

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics, data-analysis

Similar to:

[Average of products VS. product of averages](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/675924/average-of-products-vs-product-of-averages)

I have

$$
R = \{(s_1, t_1), (s_2, t_2), ..., (s_n, t_n)\}
$$

With the property that, for all pairs $(s_i, t_i)$, $0 \le s_i < t_i$.

$$
\forall (s_i, t_i) : 0 \le s_i < t_i
$$

The value of one pair, $(s_i, t_i)$ is $s_i \over t_i$

I want to select an $m$ sized subset where $m < n$ that maximizes value.

One way to compute the value of a subset $P \subseteq R$ is to take the mean of the values of the individual pairs:

$$p(P) = {1 \over m} {\sum_{i=1}^m {s_i \over t_i}}$$

Another way is to compute the value of the summed individual elements from the pairs:

$$q(P) = {\sum_{i=1}^m {s_i} \over \sum_{i=1}^m {t_i}}$$

Let $P'$ be the subset $P$ of size $m$ such that $p(P)$ is maximized.  (This is easy.  Select the $m$ elements of $R$ with highest value.)

Let $Q'$ be the subset $Q$ of size $m$ such that $q(Q)$ is maximized. (I think this requires combinatorial search.)

What is the relationship between $p(P')$ and $q(Q')$?

Will $p(P') \le q(Q')$ always?

Which is the truer maximum value?

Comment: You can get an $\epsilon$-approximation to $q(P)$ pretty quickly, say, in time I think proportional to $\log(1/\epsilon)$ and roughly linear in $n$.

Comment: Thanks to @Michael for helping to clarify the question.

Comment: Also, are the $t_i$ positive numbers? Else, you can get division by 0 errors.

Comment: Edited to clarify $0 \le s_i < t_i$.  Thanks again.  So sloppy!  Appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example with $p(P') > q(Q')$ is this:  Let $n=3,m=2$, and define the set: 
$$ \{(1,1), (1,200), (10^{-6}, 10^6)\} $$
where the pair $(10^{-6}, 10^6)$ was thrown in as an undesirable option to ensure $m<n$.  We get: 
\begin{align}
p(P') &= \frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{200}\right] = 0.5025 \\
q(Q') &= \frac{1 + 1}{1+200} \approx 0.00995
\end{align}

Now, your question about "which is the truer maximum value" does not really make sense without a definition of "truer."  The $p()$ and $q()$ functions are just different functions and so they can have different max values.

---

To find an $\epsilon$-approximation to the optimal set $Q'$ very quickly, you can do the following.  (This is similar to what I did for stochastic ratio problems in Section V of this paper: http://ee.usc.edu/stochastic-nets/docs/renewal-optimization.pdf)

#### Problem setup:

-Fix $n$ and $m$ as a positive integers with $m \leq n$.

-Fix real numbers $\{s_1, ..., s_n\}$.

-Fix positive real numbers $\{t_1, ..., t_n\}$.

Define $\mathcal{A}_m$ as the set of all subsets of $\{1, ..., n\}$ that contain $m$ elements.  Define: 
\begin{align} 
Q' &= \arg \max_{Q \in \mathcal{A}_m} \left[\frac{\sum_{i\in Q} s_i}{\sum_{i\in Q} t_i} \right] \\
M &= \max_{Q \in \mathcal{A}_m} \left[\frac{\sum_{i\in Q} s_i}{\sum_{i\in Q} t_i} \right]
\end{align}

Fix $\epsilon>0$. We want to find a set $Q \in \mathcal{A}_m$ that gives $\frac{\sum_{i\in Q} s_i}{\sum_{i\in Q} t_i} \geq M-\epsilon$.

#### Solution approach:

Define the following function $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by: 
$$ g(\mu) = \max_{Q \in \mathcal{A}_m} \left[\sum_{i \in Q} s_i - \mu \sum_{i\in Q} t_i\right] $$

It is not difficult to show:

1) For a given $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$, the value $g(\mu)$ can be easily found by selecting the $m$ indices in $\{1, ..., n\}$ with the largest values of $(s_i -\mu t_i)$.

2) The function $g(\mu)$ is strictly decreasing in $\mu$.

3) $g(\mu)=0$ if and only if $\mu=M$.

So finding an $\epsilon$-approximation reduces to approximating the zero of the decreasing function $g(\mu)$.  We can just run a simple bisection search.

Comment: I like it.  Initial lower value for $\mu$ can be zero.  How would you like to select the initial upper value for $\mu$?  Max($s_i$)?  Mean($s_i$)?

Comment: Yes, the question about truer isn't at all well specified.  If you were grading a course by combining grades from tests, and some tests had more possible points than others, which method would you consider more "fair?"  I'm having a hard time coming up with justifications myself, except that the outcome might be considered more accurate if it weights according to the possible values of the tests.

Comment: In my use case, the $t_i$ practically range from 500 up to 8000, the values are generally in range $0.5 ... 0.9$.  Rarely higher, sometimes lower.  Very occasionally zero.

Comment: To start the bisection, we need to bracket $M$ with lower and upper bounds such  that $\mu_{min} \leq M \leq \mu_{max}$.  Simple bounds are $\mu_{min} = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^m s_i}{\sum_{i=1}^m t_i}$ and  
$\mu_{max}= \max_{i \in \{1, …, n\}} (s_i/t_i)$.

Comment: For grading (continuing to assume $t_i>0$ for all $i$), the typical method is to assign nonnegative weights $w_i$ to each item $i$ (such that $\sum_{i=1}^n w_i=1$) and then compute $\sum_{i=1}^n w_i (s_i/t_i)$.

Comment: Wow, I wouldn't have realized that paper was applicable; but, did find section V(B).  Looks like $val(θ_{max}) ≤ 0$ is the key; so, $max(s_i)$ would work.  Maybe even better, $max({{s_i} \over{ t_i}})$.  Did I get it?  Aha, we're commenting together.  I did!  Thank you so much!

Comment: I have concluded that  $\sum^n_{i=1}{w_i(s_i/t_i)}$ is the same as ${\sum^n_{i=1}s_i}\over{\sum^n_{i=1}t_i}$ provided $w_i = {{t_i}\over{\sum^n_{i=1}t_i}}$